# Displaying key/value pairs

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a bunch of key/value pair text data that I need to display.

I currently use *LongListSelector* with an *ItemTemplate* which uses a horizontal *StackPanel* with two *TextBlock* s inside:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Title: " />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</StackPanel>
```

This gives a nice "label: value" look.

However, I find this verbose. 
**Is there a nicer way to achieve the same thing?**

I've tried putting everything in a single TextBlock like so:

```
<TextBlock Text="Title: {Binding Path=Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

but it doesn't want to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a single TextBlock, this is not possible. However, you could use a ValueConverter:

```
public class NameValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(Object value,
    Type targetType,
    Object parameter,
    CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "Title: " + (string)value;
    }
}
```

You should add this to your app.xaml as a global resource (named `NameValueConverter`). Then you can do this in XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title, Converter={StaticResource NameValueConverter}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

When databinding kicks in, it will pass the Title to the valueconverter and bind the result to the textbox.

Comment: The label will be changing between the pairs. Is there a way I can pass a parameter to the _NameValueConverter_ ?

Comment: You can pass a parameter to the binding, however, this cannot be DataBound since it's not a DependencyProperty, so it cannot change depending on the pair